# Manage Orientation Change in Xcode without duplicating logic

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm developing an iPhone app on Xcode version 4.6.3 using storyboards.  I was wondering if there is any way to set up my layout using the GUI storyboard interface differently for portrait and landscape.  Right now, the only solution I can see is to make 2 separate view controllers.  The problem with this is I have a lot of controls, and most of my code is in my View Controller class.  I don't want to have to duplicate all of my code just for it to work on a different orientation.  I also tried using two different views and hiding one of them based on the orientation.  I could only set up outlets for one of the views, so the code did not execute in the other orientation.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set things up so there is a rotation mask (I think that is what it is called). In interface builder you will be able to choose if you want buttons and other objects to stay in place relative to the screen bounds.

Here is a good page with some information and a video on this.

http://www.coursehero.com/courses/122/concept/3973/Handling-Rotation-in-Interface-Builder/

Comment: Thanks but my controls are too complicated to use that interface.  Also, i'm worried if I set the pixel locations manually, then it won't be consistent across iphone 4 and 5 screens.